# Sorting linked list by last name

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, selection-sort

my sort Algorithm will not really sort my list nodes if i have more than three nodes with datas. I think it changes to much nodes and doesn't break my while if a change was successfully. 
I think my sort_Name calls to much sort_bychar.
sort_Name verify the names of my data packages
sort_byChar compares the character of my both String names as CharArray
switch_Name_Data switches only the data Packages.
The Algorithm is inpriciple the selection sort.

```
void sort_Name() {
    Node node_last = getLast();
    Node node_i;
    Node node_j;
    String title_i;
    String title_j;
    char[] c_node_i;
    char[] c_node_j;

    for (int i = 0; i <= node_last.data.getId(); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < i) {
            node_i = getSpecNode(i);
            node_j = getSpecNode(j);
            title_i = node_i.data.getTitle();
            title_j = node_j.data.getTitle();

            if (node_i.data.getName_last().equals(node_j.data.getName_last())) {
                if (node_i.data.getName_first().equals(node_j.data.getName_first())) {
                    if (node_i.data.getTitle().equals("Dr.")) {
                        switch_Name_Data(node_i, node_j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (node_i.data.getName_first() != node_j.data.getName_first()) {
                    c_node_i = node_i.data.getName_first().toCharArray();
                    c_node_j = node_j.data.getName_first().toCharArray();
                    sort_byChar(node_j, node_i, c_node_i, c_node_j);
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                c_node_i = node_i.data.getName_last().toCharArray();
                c_node_j = node_j.data.getName_last().toCharArray();
                sort_byChar(node_j, node_i, c_node_i, c_node_j);
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}

private void change_id(Node n_i, Node n_j) {
    int tmp_id = n_j.data.getId();
    n_j.data.setId(n_i.data.getId());
    n_i.data.setId(tmp_id);
}

private void sort_byChar(Node iv_node_i, Node iv_node_j, char[] iv_name_i, char[] iv_name_j) {
    int k = 0;
    char[] c_node_i = iv_name_i;
    char[] c_node_j = iv_name_j;

    while (k < c_node_i.length) {
        try {
            if (c_node_i[k] == c_node_j[k]) {
                int l = k + 1;
                while (c_node_i[l] != c_node_j[l]) {
                    if (c_node_i[l] < c_node_j[l]) {
                        switch_Name_Data(iv_node_i, iv_node_j);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (c_node_i[k] < c_node_j[k]) {
                    switch_Name_Data(iv_node_i, iv_node_j);
                    break;
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            break;
        }
        k++;
    }
}

private void switch_Name_Data(Node n_i, Node n_j) {
    Data tmp_i = n_i.data;
    n_i.data = n_j.data;
    n_j.data = tmp_i;
    change_id(n_i, n_j);
}
```

Comment: test_list.insert("Zebra", "Hallo", "", 100);
  test_list.insert("Apfel", "Alfons", "", 100000);
  test_list.append("Gandalf", "Assi", "", 1000);
  test_list.append("Bern", "Bernd", "", 2000);
these are my datas. test_list.insert -> inserts data packages at the beginning of my list and test_list.append -> appends data packages at the end of my list

Comment: What's wrong with Collections.sort and LinkedList ?

Comment: i know but i have to do this

Comment: As an alternate method, rather than swap nodes, start off with an empty list that will become the sorted list. Remove nodes one at a time from the original list, and insert them into order into the initially empty list, until the original list is emptied. The logic is much simple. If you really want to swap nodes in a list, first swap whatever points to those two nodes, and then swap the pointers in the nodes. This avoids having to check for adjacent nodes.